# Translate Django group name

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin, django-translated-fields

I am creating a Django application where users will have different possible groups to manage their permissions.

I would like this application to be translatable in the future, but the group names are not translatable by default. How can I make this possible? I have thought about a few possible solutions, but I can't decide which one is best.

- Replace the template where the groups are displayed and translate the group names.
- Replace the group templates and change the `__str__` method.

Can you think of another solution?

Which one do you think is the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to override the `__str__` method of the Group model like that (in `models.py`)

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

Group.__str__ = lambda self : _(self.name)
```